# VHDL function does not compile

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to define a function in VHDL but I get

> Error: tst.vhd(4): near "subtype": syntax error

Here is the code

```
subtype word10 is bit_vector(9 downto 0);
subtype word8 is bit_vector(7 downto 0);

function tst (input : in word10) return word10 is
    variable tmp : word10;
    -- code here
    begin

    return tmp;
end tst;

entity tester is
end;

architecture tst of tester is
begin
end;
```

It is the first time I am coding in VHDL and I cant figure out what is the error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the things you are attempting to define (subtypes and functions) need to be declared inside of a library unit (package or entity) or some other body, not just hanging out on their own.  Try moving the declarations to the tester entity (ie: after the "entity tester is" line):

```
entity tester is
    subtype word10 is bit_vector(9 downto 0);
    subtype word8 is bit_vector(7 downto 0);

    function tst (input : in word10) return word10 is
        variable tmp : word10;
        -- code here
        begin

        return tmp;
    end tst;
end tester;
```

Exactly where you declare your subtypes and functions will depend on the scope where you need them to be visible.  If you need them accessible across your entire design, they are typically gathered together and declared in a package.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you have to define the `SUBTYPE` **inside** of your function between de definition and `begin`.

However, I'm not sure whether you are aware of the fact that VHDL is not something like a programming language but more a design language. If you want to synthesize your code, then you should be careful whether in your case the function can be synthesized.

Comment: If I bypass the `subtype` thing. `function tst (input : in bit_vector(9 downto 0)) return bit_vector(7 downto 0) is` I get similar error about function. I am writing this code for an fpga so you say that it may not work? I am confused.

`Error: tst.vhd(4): near "function": syntax error`

Comment: You should avoid everything like functions in VHDL, because it's nothing like C. Use `entities` for port declarations and `architecture` for behavioural declaration, nothing more. And beware statements like `wait`, because these cannot be synthesized. A good (the best IMO) book: The Designer's Guide to VHDL by Peter Ashenden.

Comment: I will implement a cryptographic algorithm in vhdl and I need something like functions otherwise the code will become pretty messy. I read about components but I think it is not what I need.

Comment: Reasonable partition all the elements into entities and connect them with their ports to a complete system. There is IMO no need for functions. Also look at the answer @CharlesSteinkuehler provided.

Answer (score 1):

`subtype`s and `function`s are usually declared within `package`s and `package body`s - if you are trying to compile that code as-is, then, yes, it will fail.

try (just typed off the top of my head, so there may be syntax typos, but it should give you the right idea):

```
package mypkg is
    subtype word10 is bit_vector(9 downto 0);
    subtype word8 is bit_vector(7 downto 0);
    function tst (input : in word10) return word10;
end package;
package body mypkg is      
    function tst (input : in word10) return word10 is
        variable tmp : word10;
    begin
        -- code here
        return tmp;
    end function;
end package body;
```

In order to "run" any code (which is a bit of a misnomer for code which intended to be describing hardware) you'll also need an `entity` to "elaborate" within the simulator in order to then call your `tst` function.  Entities are much more used as VHDL building blocks, with processes used to capture behaviours within the blocks - functions and procedures are often used within the entities and processes to capture oft-used functionality, as in the software world.